# Importing multiple images url

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So i want have a folder of images that i would like to use.

i have a images.js that has items like

```
const images = {
          John: {
                uri: require('./pictures/john.png')
          },
          Mary: {
                uri: require('./pictures/mary.png')
          },
}
export default images;
```

And say i use it in another component

```
import { images } from './images.js';


constructor(props){
    super(props);
        this.state = {
            dataSource: require('../JSON/humanNames.json'),

        }

}

_renderItem = ({item}) => (

       /* PROBLEM LIES HERE I DONT KNOW HOW TO CALL AFTER IMPORTING */
       /* I want to do it dynamically base on my json items so i will use 
         the image based on the name called from my json*/ 
        <View>
            <Image source = {images[item.name]["uri"]}/>
        </View>


);

render(){
    return(
        <View>
            <FlatList 
                data = {this.state.dataSource}
                renderItem= {this._renderItem}

                keyExtractor = {(item) => item.id}
            />

        </View>
    )      
}
```

I am trying to load the image dynamically based on the item name, as the item.name contains the names like John, mary and so on.

How would i acheive that?

My json file example is

```
[{ 
   "id": 1,
   "name": John
 },
 { 
   "id": 2,
   "name": Mary
 }]
```

Comment: no its not working, i have trouble with the calling of image in my _renderItem

Comment: whats your output of require in url and datasource? Are they loading correctly?

Comment: my url path is correct , my error is  "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_images.default[item.name]"

Comment: can you console.log your images variable and show the output?

Comment: no i can't sorry...

Comment: nope, its not that

Comment: am i accessing the images component wrongly after impoorting?

Comment: Try import images from './images.js'; as Thakur suggesting

Comment: OKAY GUYS ITS WORKING NOW, THANKS FOR YOUR HELP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is coming from this line at the beginning

```
import { images } from './images.js';
```

You are exporting it as default object so in that case you need to import like this

```
import images from './images.js';
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using named exports they must be imported with named imports. If you're using default export then they are imported as default import.

ie.

If you export,

```
export default A;
```

Then it should be imported like,

```
import A from '../somepath';
```

Else if you export by,

```
export {A};
```

Then import by,

```
import {A} from '../Somepath';
```

Comment: thanks, but i still getting the same error from my calling of <Image source = {images[item.name]["uri] } />

Comment: i referenced my idea from https://github.com/Pau1fitz/react-native-football/blob/master/components/TableBody/index.js